# What is the difference between symbol_request() and symbol_get() used (for fetching external symbols) in Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, tizen

I am trying to find the difference between symbol_request() and symbol_get() macros used for getting external symbols defined in other kernel modules.  In our code base, in some places we use symbol_request() and in some places symbol_get(). I looked at the kernel code but its not very straight-forward.  From what I have read so far, the difference has something to do with synchronous/asynchronous calls, but its still unclear due to lack of proper documentation on this.  So I have two questions.

1. What is the exact difference in functionality between symbol_request() and symbol_get() ?
2. The functionality I need is, if the external symbol was not returned (say the other module is not up yet), there has to be a mechanism to wait and try again or come back and get again later right before use. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you even tried to search for an answer before asking? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/module.h#L865 Try next time to do your homework.

Comment: Thanks but its not very helpful. I must admit that I am a newbie in kernel work. I have seen the kernel code before posting my question as well.  It goes into multiple macros taking different paths, hence its not easy to comprehend and that's why I posted the question.

Comment: The code gives you the 100% correct answer to your questions. Just read the code! That’s what my link is about. It answers your question.